# JavaScript Error: "Unknown error The operation is insecure.."

Tags: javascript, sql

I am trying to use the local database API in Safari 11, but getting:

> Unknown error The operation is insecure...

This used to work for me, but not any more.

The code is as follows:

```js
testDB = {};

function initDatabase() {
  try {
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
      alert("Databases are not supported in this browser.");
    } else {
      var shortName = 'testDB';
      var version = '1.0';
      var displayName = 'Test Database';
      var maxSize = 100000; //  bytes
      console.log('openDatabase');
      testDB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (e == 2) {
      // Version number mismatch.
      console.log("Invalid database version.");
    } else {
      console.log("Unknown error " + e.message + ".");
    }
    return;
  }
}

initDatabase();
```

I tried this in Firefox, but it seems the database API is not longer(?) supported.

Any suggestions about how I should proceed?

Comment: Are you executing this code in a **fiddle/snippet or any sandboxed environment** which has prohibited the access to these resources?

Comment: No. This is the contents of a file on my local disk. I get the error when I open the file in Safari. I've seen comments on the net about using a "Content-Security-Policy" meta tag, but I haven't been able to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Web Sql standard is no longer maintained by W3C and it's not supported by Firefox and other browsers now anymore. Check this link for more information

https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/beyond-html5-database-apis-and-the-road-to-indexeddb/

Answer (score 0):

WebSql is deprecated ,thats why browsers are removing support. You should move to indexeddb. If you want your existing sql query to use in indexeddb and dont want to deal with indexeddb complexity - you should use [JsStore](http://jsstore.net/). It provides sql like api for storing data in indexeddb.